# Android compatiblity - micromax funbook

Tags: android, android-layout, android-compatibility

I am new in android development. And I have confusion about android layout compatibility.

I am creating one app in android 4.0.3 but it's UI look like android **2.2** related UI.

I used all default controls in app but it not look like **4.0.3** related UI.

So any one can help me in below problems.

1. If I am creating app in android 4.0.3 then how it's look in android 2.2 and vice versa?
2. How can I create app which is run in all android version with standard UI?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the edit has made this question more unclear than it was

Answer (score 0):

Your app will use the system `theme` that you specify, or the custom `styles` that you specify. If you do not create custom `themes` or `styles` your app will use the default styles on each platform. So on 4.0.3 it will use the ICS theme, and on 2.2 it will use the older theme.

To create an app that will run on all versions, you should probably set your target API to 1.5, but there are few devices with 1.5 left, so you'll probably set your API target to 2.2, and this will make your application run on all the devices with Android 2.2+.

Comment: example of what? I just give you the simple explanation... where have you tested your application?